# How do I hide "nothing" value from <select> drop down list?

Tags: php, forms

I have a simple drop down list with the options male and female and the value "gender" when nothing is selected.

How do I hide "gender" from the drop down list?

Thanks

Comment: Don't put it in the list to begin with...?

Comment: I agree with deceze, or please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<option value="" disabled>Select Gender</option>
```

EDIT check it

```
jQuery("select#sel option:disabled").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I might use it if I don't get a better answer

Comment: jQuery("select#sel option:disabled").hide();

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use javascript to change the contents of the select on the  mouse down event.

This shows you how to do it, but they use a different event.
http://www.fiendish.demon.co.uk/html/javascript/listfill.html

But I think most of the time people just leave it in and check for it in the form validation step. At least that is what I would do.